# Can "albeit" be used to reference something plural?

Tags: grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Definition of “albeit” and how it's different from “although” (if it is)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45225/definition-of-albeit-and-how-its-different-from-although-if-it-is)
>   [Why don’t other pronouns get to albe-themselves, à la albeit’s “it”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65519/why-dont-other-pronouns-get-to-albe-themselves-a-la-albeits-it)

*Albeit* is defined as a way to express the phrase "although it be." But is it correct to use it to express "although they be"? E.g.

> Their techniques were effective, albeit harsh.

Would this be acceptable?

Comment: In the example sentence I would replace _albeit_ with _although_: "Their techniques were effective, although harsh."

Comment: You could replace with "although", but I think "albeit" is a little more emphatic. From that point of view they're not 100% synonymous (though of course no "synonyms" really are).

Comment: I doubt that speakers of English today think of "albeit" as being a form of "although it be", which is [now] essentially ungrammatical, but rather they simply treat it as a fixed form. Or put another way: your sentence is fine.

Comment: Besides [Definition of albeit and how its different from although if it is](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45225), see [What's the origin of the word albeit?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38652), and [Usage of commas with albeit](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10892), and aforementioned [Why dont other pronouns get to albe themselves a la albeits it](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65519),

Comment: I asked a question about "albeit" about a week back, [Why don’t other pronouns get to albe-themselves, à la albeit’s “it”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65519/why-dont-other-pronouns-get-to-albe-themselves-a-la-albeits-it), and got some interesting ansewers. Check out the info that was posted re: albeit's reference to the "Dummy It".

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly fine, though “albeit” is not conversational style. Remember that the word is an adverb, not a verbal phrase or anything like that. Its presumed history does not enter into the way it’s used.

Comment: Actually it's precisely its history that enters into the way it's used. Both you and the OP just presume [the *wrong* history](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=albeit). The "it" in *albeit* does not refer back to the preceding noun. Much rather, it's the [dummy it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun), like the one in "it's raining outside". Just like people would never say "they are raining outside", they also wouldn't say "although be they that".

Comment: That, and it isn't an adverb.